# unexpected EOF while parsing in my code? Why is this happening?

Tags: python

## Below is my code, it keeps saying that there is an unexpected EOF while parsing, especially on line 0, pos 0. Please help me out.

```
from math import sqrt

perimeter = 0

x1 = float(input("Enter the x-coordinate of the point: "))
y1 = float(input("Enter the y-coordinate of the point: "))



x0 = x1
y0 = y1

line = input("Enter the x-coordinate of the point (blank to quit) : ")

while line != "":
    x = float(line)
    y = float(input("Enter the y-coordinate of the point: "))
    
    distance = sqrt((x0 - x) ** 2 + (y0 - y) ** 2)
    perimeter = perimeter + distance
    
    x0 = x
    y0 = y
    
    line = eval(input("Enter the x-coordinate of the point (blank to quit) :"))
distance = sqrt((x1 - x0) ** 2 + (y1 - y0) ** 2)
perimeter = perimeter + distance

print("The perimeter of the polygon is",perimeter)
```

Comment: Eval is dangerous and you probably never need it. Seriously do not use eval.

Answer (score 0):

You don't require the `eval`. Remove it and it will work fine.

If the user enters nothing, `eval` is not able to parse and you're seeing that error.

Answer (score 0):

try after removing `eval` inside the while loop with `input` function

Answer (score 0):

You're running `eval()` on an empty string.

It looks like what you really want here is to parse the input into `float`

Consider this instead:

```
from math import sqrt

perimeter = 0

x1 = float(input("Enter the x-coordinate of the point: "))
y1 = float(input("Enter the y-coordinate of the point: "))



x0 = x1
y0 = y1

line = input("Enter the x-coordinate of the point (blank to quit) : ")

while line != "":
    x = float(line)
    y = float(input("Enter the y-coordinate of the point: "))

    distance = sqrt((x0 - x) ** 2 + (y0 - y) ** 2)
    perimeter = perimeter + distance

    x0 = x
    y0 = y

    line = float(input("Enter the x-coordinate of the point (blank to quit) :"))
distance = sqrt((x1 - x0) ** 2 + (y1 - y0) ** 2)
perimeter = perimeter + distance

print("The perimeter of the polygon is",perimeter)
```